# Independent events, X and Y

Tags: probability

Assume there are two events, $X$ and $Y$. The probability that event $X$ happens is equal to $2/5$ and the probability that event $Y$ happens is equal to $3/4$.
Whether or not these two events happen are independent of each other.

Therefore, the probability of both $X$ and $Y$ not happening should be $3/5  \times 1/4$ which is equal to $3/20$. Is that right?

Comment: Almost everything is fine, the multiplication is wrong.

Comment: Shouldn't it be the Pr(~X) and Pr(~Y)?

Comment: @Manuel $5\times4=9$?

Comment: Oh! My bad. I've updated it.

Comment: OK, you finally fixed the multiplication!

Comment: ok now. ${}{}{}{}$